# Changing the currency format in index page

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, session, currency, index

I am trying to set the currency format in My magento store based on the option selected by the customer. When customers click on an option in the header I am redirecting them to a page called check.php with a parameter called **curr** and I am setting a session variable based on that parameter, like below. And then redirecting them to the home page.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
        Mage::app();
       Mage::init();
       if($_GET['curr']=='usd') {
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCountry("USD");
       } else {
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCountry("INR");
       }
       header('Location: http://localhost/xyz/');
       exit();
```

once redirected I am checking the session in index.php and converting the currency based on the selection like below

```
Mage::app();
  Mage::init();   
    $currencies = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCountry();
    echo $currencies.'Akshay';
  $access_var = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getRefer();
  if(!isset($access_var)) {
      if($currencies === "USD")
    {
       Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setRefer("access");
       Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('USD');
       Mage::reset();
} else {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setRefer("unaccess");
       Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('INR');
       Mage::reset();
}
}
```

But magento is throwing an error saying **"Mage registry key "controller" already exists"**

Can anyone kindly let me know how can I resolve this.

Comment: Did you manage to achieve this?